# After upgrading to MVC 5 I see exclamation mark for the web project, though it works

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I upgraded the project to MVC 5 and now experience the problem with "exclamation mark", though it works but it is annoying to see it in the VS 2012.

I mean this sign:
[image]

Comment: Have you upgraded Visual Studio 2012 to update 4?

Comment: is this still an issue for you?

Comment: No, your answer helped. Please set is as the answer I will mark it as resolved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade Visual Studio 2012 to [Update 4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872520) and install [Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx). From the blog-

> With this release of ASP.NET and Web Tools, it is now possible for
>   developers using Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013 to
>   collaborate on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. This release brings in
>   key features such as support for ASP.NET Razor 3 editing which allows
>   developers to use syntax highlighting and Intellisense when editing a
>   Razor View in their MVC application

The Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 also-

> [addresses] compatibility and migration/round-tripping issues between
>   VS 2012 and VS 2013 and the various platform releases to make adoption
>   of VS 2013 as smooth as possible

According to [this blog post from Brian Harry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/07/30/vs-2012-4-update-4-will-exist.aspx) at Microsoft.